# What is the idiomatic way to stop the event propagation with core.async (ClojureScript)?

Tags: events, clojurescript, core.async

I have a very simple use case: in a text area, I want to stop the event propagation for *some* key codes and trigger some function `f`, and for other key codes, I just trigger some function `g`.

So I've defined a channel called `out` and a listener, which is putting all `keypress` events to the channel:

```
(events/listen
    (dom/getElement "input")
    "keypress"
    (fn [e] (put! out e)))
```

And here comes the crux: where should I stop the event propagation? To do it *after* I extracted the event from the channel seems logically to late and, as expected, doesn't work. To stop the event propagation within the handler as shown above seems to be idiomatically wrong. And I really don't want to put any logic into the pre-channel handlers: why would I use core.async then, if I do all the work in the listener directly?

So how is it supposed to work then?

Comment: take a look at core.async webinar examples - https://github.com/cognitect/async-webinar/blob/master/src/webinar/core.cljs. There are example with `filter` transducer you can adapt.

Answer (score 0):

I think @edbond's answer above is correct, and if you have versions of clojure, clojurescript and core.async that are up to date enough to support transducers, you should go with that.

If you are on an older stack, you can use the filter> fn to apply filtering on the channel:

```
(def ch (async/filter> even? (async/chan)))
(go-loop [msg (async/<! ch)] 
  (when msg 
    (println msg) 
    (recur (async/<! ch))))

(go 
  (async/put! ch 1)  ;; does nothing
  (async/put! ch 2)) ;; prints 2
```